# Lift for storing stuff above my fridge

Tags: refrigerator, storage

I want to lift stuff (chairs or a baby stroller) and store them above my fridge. 
I was thinking about installing some floor to ceiling rod and somehow connect a winch to pull some platform up and down.
The thing is that I need this system to have 2 axis, since once the platform with goods reaches its max height I need to push it back.

Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You mention that you want to store heavy stuff up above that top fridge cabinet. Have you verified yet that the cabinet can take the weight? Many cabinets just have a somewhat skimpy cross strip in the top back of the cabinet that is screwed to the wall in just two places. These days these strips may only be made of particle board that is just stapled in place on the ends.

Comment: It should be able to hold 40lbs. I was thinking about attaching a threaded rod to the wall and connect a platform to a linear actuator sliding on the rod. This way the rod will do the heavy lifting. What do you think?

Comment: Where is the airflow on your fridge?  Under the front, or up the back?

Comment: On the back side. Also, there is some 5" of space between the wall and the upper cabinet

Answer (score 1):

Buy a folding step-stool. they fold flat (about 2 inches thick)  so can be stored in many convenient places, and then can be opened and closed with one hand (which is convenient if your other hand is full)

[image]

Comment: Not the solution I was looking for. I need to lift heavy stuff repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

> It should be able to hold 40lbs. I was thinking about attaching a
>   threaded rod to the wall and connect a platform to a linear actuator
>   sliding on the rod. This way the rod will do the heavy lifting. What
>   do you think? – chegov 2 hours ago

Here is what I think:

You mentioned stowing multiple items up there. If 40lbs is the max any one item would be less than that, say 15 pounds or so in order to leave a safety margin. I suggest that for lifting up the 15 pound items that a hoist, cable system, platform with linear actuator etc are far far overkill. You will save yourself a ton of money and avoid installing a butt ugly contraption in your kitchen.

You really should consider the folding step stool as suggested by [Jasen](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/193573/7367) or even a full fledged step ladder instead of the scheme that you seem set on. Even if you did some how manage to create your contraption you would still need a stool or ladder to get up there to slide the items onto/off of the platform.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.grainger.com/product/WERNER-4-ft-375-lb-Load-Capacity-6JJ81)*</sup>

Unless these items are ones that would be very seldom used there is a strong bet on the fact that you or others in your household would quickly get very tired of the inconvenience and time needed to deploy the contraption that you may very well stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a ramp that sits on the top edge of the cupboard, then all you have to do is slide the stuff up.

All that stuff about winches etc sounds bulky, ugly and expensive.

Comment: A ramp sounds good but how can I lift things easily up and down and then push it over the cupboard? I was thinking about mounting a rack and a pinion to the wall left of the fridge but Im not sure how and if it will work